# Do Spring cloud server and client versions need to match?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

In a project I am working on, I have a server running Spring Boot 2.01 and Spring Cloud Finchley release. Can this server communicate with a Spring Cloud config server running Sping boot 1.5 and Spring Cloud version Edgware SR4? Is there any dependency between Spring Cloud client and server versions?

Comment: no, the basic http api hasn't changed.